# What ٱلْحُبُكِ truly means?

Tags: quran, tafseer, arabic

I read [this](https://quran.com/51/7) verse from the Quran:

```
وَٱلسَّمَآءِ ذَاتِ ٱلْحُبُكِ
```

Then I wanted to see what the true meaning of `ٱلْحُبُكِ` could be.

I tried [Almaany](https://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D8%AD%D9%8F%D8%A8%D9%8F%D9%83%D9%90/) but all those diacritics makes it extremely difficult to find out the meaning of that word.

The reason I'm asking this, is that we see a lot of different meanings for this word across translations. And maybe, just maybe, based on new scientific discoveries a true new meaning can emerge for it.

For example, in [the verse](https://quran.com/51/47):

```
وَٱلسَّمَآءَ بَنَيْنَـٰهَا بِأَيْي۟دٍۢ وَإِنَّا لَمُوسِعُونَ
```

Only after discovering that the universe is expanding (dark energy) we can truly understand the meaning of `لَمُوسِعُونَ`. So the translation of this word was not available to human being for like 1350 years.

Now I'm reading about gravitational waves and electromagnetic waves and the entire universe is somehow filled with them and I want to see if the `ٱلْحُبُكِ` can mean **curl** (wave)?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.almaany.com/quran/51/7/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%92%D8%AD%D9%8F%D8%A8%D9%8F%D9%83%D9%90/) helpful for you? almaany has a special search for quranic terms!